# Is there a way to animate using css an Image rotation on mobile orientation change?

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, orientation

Right now when orientation changes on mobile with rotation unlocked, the content of the page rotates 90 degrees. Is it possible to animate this rotation? How can I achieve this using React.js?

Comment: I tried listening to onOrientationChange event but this event is sent after the automatic rotation completes.

Comment: Try using `@media (orientation: landscape) { ... }` and `@media (orientation: portrait) { ... }`. They will get triggered when the viewport width becomes smaller than its height and v.v. I don't use React, but this should work regardless...